# How to echo from specific line of a file to another specific line

Tags: sed, awk, tail, text, head

Assume I have a file with about 10000 lines.

How can I print 100 lines, starting from line 1200 to line 1300?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk this would be `awk 'NR >= 1200 && NR <= 1300'`

with sed: `sed -n '1200,1300 p' FILE`

with head and tail: `head -n 1300 FILE | tail -n 100`

so many options, so many answers on stackexchange :)

Comment: I suggest that this page be fixed. The page question is "How to echo from specific line of a file to another specific line" yet the answer is a non-sequitur regarding how to print a range of lines.

Comment: Answer to question as asked:
Insert line 3 from a file named things.txt to line 6 of a file named numbers.txt using head tail and ex:

LINE=$(head -3 things.txt |tail -1)
ex numbers.txt <<eof
6 insert
"$LINE"
.
xit
eof

#--------

Append rather than insert to say, line 6 do the following with sed:

LINE=$(head -3 things.txt |tail -1)
sed '6s/$/ "$LINE"/' numbers.txt

-----
This use of sed will only echo the change without writing it, if you want to save the changes you can echo the output to a new file

sed '6s/$/ "$LINE"/' numbers.txt >numbers2.txt